# How to load a Java agent at runtime using C++

Tags: java, c++, jvm, jvmti

I want to load a Java agent at runtime without Restarting the JVM I know that I can load the agent with the -javaagent argument when starting the JVM but I want to do it at runtime.

I found out that is possible using Sun tools but when I tried to do that in C++ and JNI it doesn't work and it can't find the required Java functions.

Comment: [jattach](https://github.com/jattach/jattach/) project (written in C) does exactly that.

Comment: @apangin I tried that but it doesn't seems to be working it returns:

Connected to remote process
Response code = 0
return code: 100

and the agent is also not loaded

Comment: This is an issue with the agent: perhaps, it does not export `Agent_OnAttach`, or the required dependency is missing.